# Find if adjacent rows have values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C2 
AA  1  3  7  4        
BB   
CC  
DD  2  5        A   1
```

I want to know if any value is used in either column C1 or C2 if the adjacent rows have empty values. In the example above, the output would be true only in row DD since a value is found in C2 and the B1 and B2 are empty. I want to examine each row and know if this instance ever occurs.

I've tried several different ways to get this done. I mostly use the `.all()` and `.any()` methods, but I haven't had any success. These methods seem to be absolute, but I'm looking to examine by each row instead. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create seperate boolean conditions, then filter your dataframe the target `ID`

```
## replace whitespace with actually na values.
import numpy as np 
df = df.replace('\s',np.nan)

s = (~df[['C1','C2']].isnull()).sum(axis=1).gt(0)

s1 = df.filter(regex='A|B').isnull().any(axis=1)


print(df.loc[s & s1,'ID'])


3    DD
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

---

### Boolean filtering

```
print(df)

   ID   A1   A2   B1   B2   C1   C2
0  AA  1.0  3.0  7.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
1  BB  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  CC  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  DD  2.0  5.0  NaN  NaN    A  1.0


print((~df[['C1','C2']].isnull()))

      C1     C2
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3   True   True
```

^ these can be turned into sums to measure conditions.

Comment: This is great! Although I realize you're using greater than 0. I'll update the example, but columns C1 and C2 will have a string and number type. Any suggests with that dataset?

Comment: @ApacheOne it does not matter as we are turning them into `booleans` so we are evaluating `1`s and `0`s essentially (`True`/`False` respectively)

Comment: @ApacheOne good luck - see edit and make sure you replace the whitespace for actual `NA` values

Comment: I have some code already taking care of the white space replacement. Your solution worked exactly as explained. Thanks again!